# STL error: use of deleted function when sorting a vector of objects in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl, c++14

I have a view class with private vector of subviews

```
class MyView {

 private:
   const std::vector<MySubView> subViews_;
}
```

In the subview I have these methods:

```
class MySubView {
  public:
    const Id getId() const {
        return id_;
    }
    const TimePoint getStartTime() const {
        return startTime_;
    }
  private:
    const Id id_;
    const TimePoint startTime_;

}
```

Now in the one of the methods that constructor of MyView calls, I'm generating this array of subviews and set it, which works fine. The problem comes when I try to sort it before assigning.

```
static std::vector<MySubViews> buildLimitViews(
  const ViewData& data);
```

When I try to sort the vector after building it in this method. I see errors. Sorting is the only part here that does not work.

```
std::vector<MySubView> buildLimitViews(
  const ViewData& data) {
    std::vector<MySubView> subViews;
    //create views from data and push them in this vector, works fine.

    // this sort block below does not work, causes errors.
      std::sort(
          subViews.begin(),
          subViews.end(),
          [](const MySubView& lhs,
             const MySubView& rhs) {
            if (lhs.getStartTime() == rhs.getStartTime()) {
              return lhs.getId() < rhs.getId();
            }
            return lhs.getStartTime() < rhs.getStartTime();
          });

    return subViews;
 }
```

If I comment out the sort block it works fine, otherwise I see this error:

> error: use of deleted function 'MySubView&
>   MySubView::operator=(MySubView&&)'

Comment: You have to post more about your `MySubView`. Posting the full class definition is a good idea. The problem is in the definition of `MySubView`, but it is in something you haven't shown yet.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  Me need at least to see the full declaration of `MySubView`.

Comment: @AnT updated MySubView, there isn't much there except few private variables and const getters.

Comment: `const` data members in your `MySubView` are the problem. Get rid of `const` in data member declarations and rely of method-based access control.

Answer (score 1):

Having `const` non-static member variables breaks assignment, because you cannot modify them.  Make `subViews_` non-`const` and it should work.

Comment: The OP is not sorting `subViews_` but instead they are sorting the non const function local `subViews`.

Comment: Ah, true.  I'm still guessing that his MySubView class does the same kind of thing with const members (but at this point it is just a guess).

Comment: I tried removing const from (const MySubView& lhs, const MySubView& rhs) but got the same error.

Comment: If you have any const non-static member variables (or you have member variables which are references) in MySubView, remove the const.  Const member functions or functions taking const references as parameters are okay.